# Why subset W of cartesian product $X\times Y$ cannot be X

Tags: set-theory

Let $W\subseteq X\times Y$ where $\forall x\in X , \exists ! y\in Y , (x,y) \in W $.

How to prove that if $W\neq \emptyset$ then always $W \neq X$ ?

I try to prove that $x = (x,y)$ cannot exist - however I realize that maybe my assumption that if $W = X$ then $x = (x,y)$ is wrong - at least maybe I should first prove that if $z\neq x$ then $x \neq (z,y)$ - I am stuck and don't know how to do it - or maybe I have done it wrong from the beginning. How can I do it?

I asume that we use ZF (or ZFC if necessarily). We can assume that pair is encoded by Kuratowski formula $(x,y)=\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$

Comment: The empty set is a subset of its cartesian product.

Comment: @JohnDouma you are right - I fix my question for this corner case

Comment: Moreover, if I understand the question correctly, it is entirely dependent on how you choose to encode ordered pairs as ZF-sets.

Comment: @user43208 can you show counter example - choose pair definition, and sets X and Y - and show that $X=X\times Y$

Comment: Your title suggests you are asking why $X\not\subset X\times Y$, but the post asks $X\neq X\times Y$. Which is it?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I can create an artificial definition of $X \times Y$ where $X = X \times \{\ast\}$ for some singleton $\ast$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you are right - my bad - I fix errors

Comment: It also depends on your set theory. There are non-well-founded theories where $S=S\times T$ can happen for $S\neq\varnothing$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1290270/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I assume that we use ZF - maybe ZFC if needed

Comment: Still asking a different question in your title and your post. Still need to specify how you encode ordered pairs. Still failing to state your full assumptions in your post, rather than bury incomments the fact that you are working in ZF.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - now is more clear?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin way of encoding pairs (as some sets) - change something? However we can assume that we use Kuratowski pair encoding $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$

Comment: Don't hide critical information in the comments. Put it in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer will necessarily be non-intuitive, as it depends on the Axiom of Foundation (in non-well-founded Set Theories, [it is possible for a nonempty set $S$ to satisfy $S=S\times T$ for some set $T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1290270/742)).

I will assume that whatever encoding you have for ordered pairs and for $X\times Y$, it sastisfies the following: if $(x,y)\in X\times Y$, then there exists $z\in (x,y)$ such that $x\in z$. This holds for the Kuratowski definition, $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, with $z=\{x\}$.

The argument below can easily be adapted to other encodings that require longer, but finite,  $\in$-"chains": that is, the existence of sets $z_1,\ldots,z_k$ such that $x\in z_1$, $z_1\in z_2,\ldots, z_{k-1}\in z_k$, $z_k\in (x,y)$. This holds, for example, for the Wiener definition of ordered pair, $(a,b)=\{\{\{a\},\varnothing\},\{\{b\}\}\}$, where we have $z_1$ and $z_2$ with $a\in z_1$, $z_1\in z_2$, $z_2\in (a,b)$, with $z_1=\{a\}$, $z_2=\{\{a\},\varnothing\}$.

Assume $X\neq\varnothing$, and $X=X\times Y$ for some $Y$. Let $x_0\in X$. Then there exist $(x_1,y_1)\in X\times Y$ such that $x_0=(x_1,y_1)$ with $x_1\in X$, $y_1\in Y$. Therefore, there exist $z_1$ such that $x_1\in z_1$, $z_1\in (x_1,y_1)=x_0$.

Now since $x_1\in X$, there exist $x_2\in X$, $y_2\in Y$, and $z_2\in (x_2,y_2)$ such that $x_1=(x_2,y_2)$, and $x_2\in z_2$, $z_2\in (x_2,y_2)=x_1$. Thus we have
$$x_2\in z_2\in x_1\in z_1\in x_0.$$
Recursively, using the Axiom of (Dependent) Choice, we obtain an infinite descending sequence of sets,
$$\cdots x_{n+1}\in z_{n+1}\in x_n \in z_n \in \cdots \in x_1\in z_1\in x_0.$$
In $\mathsf{ZF}$ with the Axiom of Foundation and the Axiom of (Dependent) Choice, [there is no function $f$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$ which takes sets as values, and with the property that $f(n+1)\in f(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists); that is, there are no infinite descending $\in$-chains in $\mathsf{Sets}$. Thus, we have arrived at a contradiction from the assumption that $X\neq\varnothing$ and $X=X\times Y$ for some set $Y$.

I expect that with specific definitions of $(x,y)$ one may be able to avoid the Axiom of (Dependent) Choice, and rely only on the Axiom of Foundation, but I won't attempt it, as in any case the solution is likely to be unsatisfying non-intuitive. We expect that a set $X$ with $X=X\times Y$, $X\neq\varnothing$, would be a rather "weird" set anyway.

Comment: Have you tried using the rank of sets? It might give a choice-free proof.

Comment: @HanulJeon No, I have not; I don't really feel the need to delve that deeply.

Comment: Let $x_0\in X$ of least rank.  Since $X\subseteq X\times Y$, there is an $x_1\in X,y_1\in Y$ such that $x_0=(x_1,y_1)$.  But $\operatorname{rank}((x,y))=\max\{\operatorname{rank}(x),\operatorname{rank}(y)\}+2$, so $\operatorname{rank}(x_1)<\operatorname{rank}(x_0)$ - contradiction.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Professor Arturo, I have read your proof and understood it well, but I didn't understand where you applied the axiom of choice. I think the proof can be done without it. Is this correct, or is there a point I missed?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin is this proof still valid for nonempty $W\subseteq X\times Y$ - so is allways  $W\neq X$?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski The proof shows that if $X\neq\varnothing$, then $X\not\subseteq X\times Y$. Which part is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Kuratowski's definition for ordered pairs is widely accepted: $(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$. It is also accepted that for sets $X, Y$ the cartesian product is the set of their ordered pairs. Finally for ordered pairs $(x_1,x_2) = (a,b)$ if and only if $x_1 = a$ and $x_2 = b$.

Assume $W$ is not empty and $W= X$, then there exists $(a,b) \in W$ such that $(a,b) \in X$, $b \in Y$  , then that set contains the singleton set of ordered pair $\{(a,b)\} = \{(a,b) \} \times \{b \}$. From this we get

$$\{(a,b) \} \times \{b \} \} = (\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}, b)$$

We would then have from the equality of ordered pairs and singletons, that $\{b\}=\{b\}$ and $\{a\}=\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$. We need the cardinalities of the sets to match, therefore we need $a=b$ (as then $\{a,b\} = \{a\}$ and sets do not contain multiple elements). But the proposition that $(a,b)$ exists was free. We have a contradiction which completes the proof.  Also in naive set theory we can consider $a,b$ to be atoms, which do not have any other expression than themselves.

Comment: you write "then that set contains the singleton set" - can you explain which set contains - and why it contains this singleton set ?

Comment: I used the concept of singleton to show the (in)equality which gives the contradiction using cardinality. I believe I have used the brackets correctly, but it is quite confusing. For a more high level proof I believe axiom of regularity and axiom of pairing prove $W \neq X$ instantly.

Comment: thank you for this additional information. Can you answer my previous question - because it is quite not clear for me... ?